# Rewrite / Mask multiple URLs to same url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have multiple URLs or more accurately a single URL with query strings that I would all like to read as the same URL.

- /example/url/index.php?foo=A&bar=B
- /example/url/index.php?foo=C&bar=D
- /example/url/index.php?foo=E&bar=F

I would like these to all rewrite to a single URL

Rewrite to www.site.com/singlepage

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/example/url/index.php(.*)$ http://www.site.com/simglepage [R]
```

[Here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) is a nice site describing how URL rewriting works

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible! In your `.htaccess` file, use the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^singlepage$ /example/url/index.php [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you want to externally redirect all those URLs to a single URL. Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+/example/url/index\.php\?foo=[^&]*&bar= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ singlepage? [R=302,L]
```

Once you verify everything is working fine, you can replace `R=302` with `R=301` (**permanent redirect**).